# How can I use Hibernate to load a list of entities and a subset of those entities' related entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, outer-join

I have a query I'd like to run against a table, let's call it `parent` where I'm grabbing all rows that match a certain criteria. In SQL:

```
select * from parent where status = 'COMPLETE';
```

I have this table and another related table (`child`) defined as Hibernate entities such that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children;
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    @Column(name = "key")
    private String key;
    //...
}
```

I'd like my query to ALSO pull two optional child records where `key` is one of two values. So, in SQL:

```
select *
from parent p, child ca, child cb
where p.status = 'COMPLETED'
and p.id *= ca.parent_id
and ca.key = 'FIRST_KEY'
and p.id *= cb.parent_id
and cb.key = 'SECOND_KEY';
```

I could do this in Hibernate by just grabbing the result from the first query and iterating over the `children` collection looking for the rows I want but that's terribly inefficient: one query that does two outer joins vs one query + an additional query for each looking for the children I care about.

Is there a way to replicate the outer joins in the query above in Hibernate where the objects returned will have the `children` collection only populated with the two (or less, since they are optional) entities I am interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two outer joins. You could simply use this HQL and Hibernate will add the right children to the right parent:

```
List<Parent> parentList = session
        .createQuery("from Parent p left join fetch p.children c" +
                     " where p.status = 'COMPLETE' " + 
                     " and (c.key = 'FIRST_KEY' or c.key = 'SECOND_KEY')")
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .list();

for(Parent parent:parentList) {
    System.out.println(parent);;
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm accepting this solution but after much research, it turns out what I needed was the ability to specify an "on" clause on the join to restrict the outer join table. Hibernate supports this with the `with` clause but that isn't working for me either. Getting a `antlr.SemanticException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters`. Your solution will work if you're sure the values will be there in the outer join table. If the records might not be there, the query won't retrieve the records you'd expect.